# Difference between induced emf in a loop and a wire

Tags: induction

[image]

In the given figure, I was asked to calculate induced emf in the loop and individual wires of the triangle.

I have a doubt that when I am calculating the emf of the whole loop, between which two points I have to calculate, or I have to do something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

motional emf = $\mathcal E=\displaystyle\oint(\vec v\times\vec B).\vec{dl}$

for arm AB induced emf will be zero because $(\vec v\times\vec B) $is $\perp$ to $\vec dl$

$\mathcal E_{ab}=0 $      (insert a battery of zero voltage  in arm ab)

in arm BC,

$\mathcal E_{bc}=vBl_{bc}$ (insert a battery of this magnitude with it's positive terminal at B)

in $\triangle $ABC

let $\measuredangle CAB=\theta $ then velocity of arm AC can be resolved in two directions i.e,

$vcos\theta-$ along the arm AC

and ,

$vsin\theta-$ $\perp$ to the arm AC

the latter component of velocity will cause emf induced in it.

$\mathcal{E_{ac}}=vBl_{ac}sin\theta =vBl_{bc}=\mathcal{E_{bc}}$

(insert a battery of this magnitude with positive terminal at A and negative terminal at C)

now, apply KVL in loop ABC

$V_{induced}=\mathcal{E_{ac}}+\mathcal{E_{cb}}+\mathcal{E_{ba}}=\mathcal{E_{ac}}-\mathcal{E_{bc}}+0=\mathcal{E_{bc}}-\mathcal{E_{bc}}=0$

so, in loop there will be no net emf induced.

Answer (score 0):

The above-stated problem is based on **motional EMF** in which $$\mathcal{E}=\bigl(\overrightarrow{v}\times\overrightarrow{B}\bigr)\cdot\Delta\overrightarrow{l}$$ where $\Delta\overrightarrow{l}$ represents the projection of length along the vector perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{v}$.
In this particular example, we have only two portions of conductor in which EMF will be induced, namely **AC** and **BC**(*Notice that I'm putting higher potential points first*).

There won't be any induced EMF in **AB** because $\bigl(\overrightarrow{v}\times\overrightarrow{B}\bigr)\cdot\Delta\overrightarrow{l}$ vanishes. Considering all this, we are left with:
$$\mathcal{E}_{AC}=vBl_{BC}=-\mathcal{E}_{BC}$$
Therefore $\mathcal{E}_{total}=\mathcal{E}_{AC}+\mathcal{E}_{BC}=0$ .

This also complies with **Faraday's Law** which states that $$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = \oint{\overrightarrow{E}\cdot\overrightarrow{dl}}=\mathcal{E}_{total}$$
This is because the magnetic flux passing through the loop is constant, i.e $\dfrac{d\phi}{dt}=0$ , therefore no EMF is induced.

Comment: Current should flow in the direction CB. So, C should be at higher potential.

Comment: No, B will be at higher potential.

Comment: yes ,B will be at higher potential ,because in arm CB the magnetic force $q(\vec v \times \vec B)$ acts in downward direction (from C to B) which leads to the drift of positive charges  from C to  B . and to counter  this magnetic force an electric field is devloped from B to C which in turn cause potential difference to be devloped between both ends (C,B) of arm CB